# Monerod frequent error (duplicate key: support_flags)

Tags: monerod

I've been running a Monero node for over a year and suddenly started getting the error below. I re-installed `monerod` and downloaded a new blockchain, but still receiving this frequent error:

```
2023-09-21 01:19:57.696 E duplicate key: support_flags
2023-09-21 01:19:57.696 E Exception at [portable_storage::load_from_binary], what=duplicate key: support_flags
```

Any help with interpreting or correcting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> You can ignore it, someone is sending you invalid p2p packets. Happens on a lot of nodes but doesn't cause any issues.

-- selsta ([ref](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/8995#issuecomment-1723327953)).

This could be a badly written fork or a poorly modified / configured node. In any case, it can be safely ignored.